# How to print strange old type cursor

Tags: oracle

I have a cursor

```
 CURSOR c_trd(pi_bps_batch_seq VARCHAR2) IS    
    SELECT    
      bps_batch_seq    
      , hetid    
      , op_code    
      , seg_data    
      , xmit_dt    
      , xmit_batch_file    
      , blotter_code    
      , fn_bos(contra_party_acct,hcact,minor_clr_broker) BOS_O    
      , bos      
      , ats_ind    
      ,CASE tob_ind    
        WHEN  NULL THEN tob_ind    
        WHEN 'M930' THEN  'MH'    
       END    
    FROM intact_msrb_vw A         
    WHERE bps_batch_seq = pi_bps_batch_seq                 AND    
      xmit_dt       IS NULL    
    FOR UPDATE OF xmit_dt,xmit_batch_file,bos    
    ;    

     lv_next_seq      tran_queue_bps_batch.bps_batch_seq%TYPE;
```

How can I print cursor value?
It is not my SP, very old, and I don't understand, what is

```
pi_bps_batch_seq VARCHAR2
```

in the cursor.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "print cursor value"? . You can just run the select statement  by replacing `pi_bps_batch_seq`  with a value  and see for yourself. And why do you think it's "old type cursor"?

Comment: I want to print it in the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

The `CURSOR` is not "strange old type cursor". It is a `CURSOR` with a  parameter .  `pi_bps_batch_seq VARCHAR2`  should be an argument while opening the cursor.

In your stored procedure, you can open and fetch from the `CURSOR` as follows.

```
OPEN c_trd( <value_for_pi_bps_batch_seq>);
LOOP
FETCH c_trd INTO ....
```

when you `OPEN` the cursor like this , the RHS in `WHERE bps_batch_seq = pi_bps_batch_seq`
will be replaced by the value you pass.

**EDIT:**

> but how can I print value of the cursor in SP? DBMS.OUTPUT-PUTLINE?

Here is one way.

```
for cur IN c_trd( <value_for_pi_bps_batch_seq>)
LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur.bps_batch_seq , cur.hetid,....); 
END LOOP;
```

Comment: but how can I print value of the cursor in SP? DBMS.OUTPUT-PUTLINE?